# How to retrieve job names via bamboo API

Tags: curl, bamboo

I'm struggling with getting the actual job names via bamboo (server) API.

with `curl --request GET --url 'http://{baseurl}/rest/api/latest/result/{projectKey}-{buildKey}/{buildNumber}' --header 'Accept: application/json'` I can dig down to stages, but I am not able to retrieve the name of the included jobs. I already read through the [api documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/bamboo/rest/api-group-api/#api-group-api).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `?expand\=stages.stage.plans` lets me retrieve the information

Comment: My experience with the API has been to read the API docs to figure out the "big picture" call to make, then watch the API return to see what's "expandable", and then poke at _each_ of those to figure out what I really need.  I wish the API docs were a little bit nicer that way.  Though to be fair, the API _does_ enumerate all of the expand-able items, which is pretty nice.  It'd be even better if the API docs would tell you what all of those expansions actually were, and what formats they support...

Comment: could not agree more!